# How can I intercept a mouse-click-event in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mouselistener

I created a base line navigation with buttons but I dont't have any idea how from Javascript intercept a mouse-click event. How to get the click position I know, but this procedure needs to be activated by the here asked mouse-event.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: See: [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Respect to every answer I got to this question and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2 onclick="showCoords(event)">Click this heading to get the x (horizontal) and y (vertical) coordinates of the mouse pointer when it was clicked.</h2>

<p><strong>Tip:</strong> Try to click different places in the heading.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function showCoords(event) {
  var x = event.clientX;
  var y = event.clientY;
  var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coords;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```